# React.js: Call functions from another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm new to React.js, confused about linking two functions in different components.

I'm trying to achieve the communication between two components. React-leaflet is quite difficult for me, so I'm using an ugly way to achieve this goal below:

So, this is my parent component, there's a table inside, which has a 'handleOnRowSelected' function. I would like my other component (which is a map) has a function, so when users click on the map component, the table component also will trigger the 'handleOnRowSelected' function.

thnx a lot if you could help me!

```
class Pd extends Component {

    state = {  
        counties:[],
        allCountyTotal:0,
        service:[],
        selectedCounties:[],
    };

    url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/magluie/mappd/master/agegender.csv';

    async componentDidMount () {
        const response = await axios.get(this.url);
        const rows = response.data.split("\n");
        console.log(rows[0].split(","));

        const counties = [];
        const service = [];


        let allCountyTotal = 0;

        for( let i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            const row = rows[i].split(",");
            const countyName = row[0];
            const atwenty = Number(row[1]);
            const athirty = Number(row[2]);
            const afourty = Number(row[3]);
            const afifty1 = Number(row[4]);
            const afifty2 = Number(row[5]);
            const asixty1 = Number(row[6]);
            const asixty2 = Number(row[7]);
            const aseventy1 = Number(row[8]);
            const aseventy2 = Number(row[9]);
            const aeighty1 = Number(row[10]);
            const aeighty2 = Number(row[11]);
            const malenum = Number(row[12]);
            const femalenum = Number(row[13]);
            const total = Number(row[14]);
            const serviceName = row[15]
       

            if(countyName !== "" && serviceName !== "") {
               
                counties.push({
                    name:countyName,
                    total: total,
                    female: femalenum,
                    male: malenum,
                    twenty: atwenty,
                    thirty: athirty,
                    fourty: afourty,
                    fifty1: afifty1,
                    fifty2: afifty2,
                    sixty1: asixty1,
                    sixty2: asixty2,
                    seventy1:aseventy1,
                    seventy2: aseventy2,
                    eighty1: aeighty1,
                    eighty2:aeighty2,
                
                    service: serviceName,

                });
            }

        }

     
        this.setState({
            counties:counties,
            allCountyTotal:allCountyTotal,
            service:service,
        });
    }

   
    handleOnRowSelected =(countyToUpdate) =>{
        const counties =[...this.state.counties];
        const countyIndex = counties.findIndex(
            (c) => c.name === countyToUpdate.name,
            (c) => c.female === countyToUpdate.female,
            (c) => c.male === countyToUpdate.male,
            (c) => c.twenty=== countyToUpdate.twenty,
            (c) => c.thirty === countyToUpdate.thirty,
            (c) => c.fourty === countyToUpdate.fourty,
            (c) => c.fifty1 === countyToUpdate.fifty1,
            (c) => c.fifty2 === countyToUpdate.fifty2,
            (c) => c.sixty1 === countyToUpdate.sixty1,
            (c) => c.sixty2 === countyToUpdate.sixty2,
            (c) => c.seventy1 === countyToUpdate.seventy1,
            (c) => c.seventy2 === countyToUpdate.seventy2,
            (c) => c.eighty1 === countyToUpdate.eighty1,
            (c) => c.eighty2 === countyToUpdate.eighty2,
        );
        const county = {
            name: countyToUpdate.name,
            total: countyToUpdate.total,
            service: countyToUpdate.service,
            female: countyToUpdate.female,
            male: countyToUpdate.male,
            twenty: countyToUpdate.twenty,
            thirty: countyToUpdate.thirty,
            fourty: countyToUpdate.fourty,
            fifty1: countyToUpdate.fifty1,
            fifty2: countyToUpdate.fifty2,
            sixty1: countyToUpdate.sixty1,
            sixty2: countyToUpdate.sixty2,
            seventy1:countyToUpdate.seventy1,
            seventy2: countyToUpdate.seventy2,
            eighty1: countyToUpdate.eighty1,
            eighty2:countyToUpdate.eighty2,

            //get the oppisit value
            selected: !countyToUpdate.selected,
        };
       
        
        counties[countyIndex] = county;
        this.setState({counties, selectedCounties: counties.filter((c) =>c.selected),
        });
    };

    sortByTotal =(countyA, countyB) =>{
        if(countyB.total > countyA.total) return 1;
        else if (countyB.total <countyA.total) return -1;
        else return 0;
    };

    handleOnSortByTotal = (event) =>{
        this.handleOnSort(event, this.sortByTotal);
    };

    sortByCountyName =(countyA, countyB) =>{
        if(countyA.name > countyB.name) return 1;
        else if (countyA.name <countyB.name) return -1;
        else return 0;
    };

    handleOnSortByCountyName = (event) =>{
       this.handleOnSort(event, this.sortByCountyName);
    };

    handleOnSort = (event,sortBy) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        const counties = [...this.state.counties]
        counties.sort(sortBy);

        this.setState({counties});

    };


    render() {
        const { counties, allCountyTotal, selectedCounties}=this.state;

        return (           
            <div>
            <MyMap />

                    <CountyTable 
                counties = {counties} 
                onSortByTotal = {this.handleOnSortByTotal} 
                onSortByCountyName = {this.handleOnSortByCountyName} 
                onRowSelected = {this.handleOnRowSelected}
                
                /> 
    
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Pd;
```

Here is the Map component:

```
const DEFAULT_LONGITUDE = 51.903614;
const DEFAULT_LATITUDE = -8.468399;



const mapstyle = {
    height: '600px',
    width: '500px',
    background:0,
    marginLeft: '50%',
    marginTop: '3%',
    marginBottom: '0.005%'
};

const contystyle = {
    fillColor:'darkgreen',
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    color: 'white',
    dashArray: '3',
    fillOpacity: 0.7
}




class  MyMap extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.callHandleOnRowSelected = this.callHandleOnRowSelected.bind(this);
        this.handleOnRowSelected = this.handleOnRowSelected.bind(this);
    }

    callHandleOnRowSelected = () => {
        this.handleOnRowSelected()
    };

    //functions for map
    highLightCounty = (event) =>{
        event.target.setStyle({
            weight:5,
            color:'white',
            fillColor:'yellow',
            fillOpacity:0.6
         });
    };
    //resethighlight county style
    resetCountyColor = (event) => {
        event.target.setStyle({
            fillColor:'darkgreen',
            weight: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            color: 'white',
            dashArray: '3',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        });
    };

    // callHandleOnRowSelected = (event) =>{
    //     this.handleOnRowSelected()
    // };
    
    // functions for features of the map
    onEachCountry = (country, layer) => {
    const countryName = country.properties.NAME_TAG;
    console.log(countryName);
    layer.bindPopup(countryName);

    layer.on({
        mouseover: this.highLightCounty,
        mouseout: this.resetCountyColor,
        click: this.callHandleOnRowSelected,
      
        });
    };
    
    
    

    render() {
        const Component = ({func}) => {
            handleOnRowSelected () 
        };


        return (
            <div>

                <Map style={mapstyle} 
                zoom = {6.5} 
                center={[latitude, longitude]}
                maxZoom={10}
                attributionControl={true}
                zoomControl={true}
                doubleClickZoom={true}
                scrollWheelZoom={true}
                dragging={true}
                animate={true}
                easeLinearity={0.35}>
                    
                    <GeoJSON 
                style={contystyle} 
                data = {mapData.features}
                onEachFeature = {this.onEachCounty} 
                />

                </Map>

        </div>
        );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass in your parent method as a prop of your child component. Your Map component should have props as part of the constructor, and then call your function on your children component by taking the function passed by the prop.

// parentComponent.jsx

```
  // something here ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div><ChildComponent onClick={this.onWhatever} /></div>
    )
  }
```

// childComponent.jsx

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      his.onSomething = this.onSomething.bind(this);
  }
      
  onSomething = () => {
    const {onClick} = this.props;
    onClick();
  }
  // other things here ...
}
```

I'd recommend using React Hooks since your child component returns a functional component anyway. I'd not bother dealing with Redux unless you have a proper understanding on React (even if it is a nice-to-haves when you're sharing state for multiple things).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have just tried that, and it worked! Thanks for your advice! Yea, I agree, I might change another method to achieve the communication features as it looks a bit complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using redux, you may consider using redux thunk or redux saga. If you are not, do consider using redux. The developers of redux also provided redux toolkit that does the hard work of wiring redux, react-redux, and redux-thunk for you.

[Redux](https://redux.js.org/) [React Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) [Redux Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/)

To explain why:

I believe your problem is about state management. You need a function to happen in a target component (which changes the state of target component) when state of source component changes.

In this case you should wire all the states through parent component (moving the state up) and also provide the functions from the parent component through props.

This problem is common and will often be found in other parts of your react components.

The state part of the problem is solved by introducing redux. The function part of the problem is partially solved by redux if the function simply changes state, and the rest solved by introducing redux saga or redux thunk.

Comment: Thanks, Willi! You're right, I gotta see another way to do it...and that's a good explanation! appreciate it!